# How to prove that this function is bijective?

Tags: real-analysis

Function $f : \Bbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ is defined as 
$f(n) = \begin{cases} 2n, & n \ge 0\\ -2n - 1, & n < 0 \end{cases}$.

I have already done following: $f(n) = 2n$. Let's choose $n_1, n_2 \ge 0$ such that $n_1 \ne n_2$. Now $2n_1 \ne 2n_2$ so $f(n_1) \ne f(n_2)$.

Surjective: $f(n) = 2n$. $y = 2n \implies y/2 = n$. So this is surjective.

But how to prove that other part of function, when $n < 0$, doesn't get same $y$-values than $n$ in $n \ge 0$ part of function? Is it enough to say that it gets odd values, while other part of function gets even values, and then I just prove that it is also surjective and injective?

Comment: Note that $f(n) \ge 0$ for all $n$. The function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ is bijective.

Comment: The codomain must be $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: That may be my bad on the codomain.  I'll just rollback the edit and let someone else deal with it.  EDIT:  Can't rollback while another edit is pending.  Sigh.

Comment: Since you said that you meant  $\mathbb N$, I just edited it for you :)

Comment: I might have made a mistake, but function is from Z to N u 0. Now it is correct.

Comment: The comment I'm replying to has been removed, but for the sake of future visitors:  OP didn't specify $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$, I did.  The codomain was not explicitly given and I assumed at first that it was the same as the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $f : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{N}_0$ as defined in the post, where I'm using $\Bbb{N}_0$ to denote $\Bbb{N} \cup \{0\} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$, then we can show surjectivity as follows:

Let $m \in \Bbb{N}$ and suppose $m$ is even.  Then because $m$ is even we know that there must be some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $m = 2k$.  We want to show that there is some $n \in \Bbb{N}_0$ such that $f(n) = m$.  We have two pieces of $f(n)$ we can try:  $f(n) = 2n$ or $f(n) = -2n-1$.  The clear choice is $f(n) = 2n$ because we want $f(n) = m$, and recall that $m=2k$.  So then $f(n) = 2n = m = 2k$.  The equality we care about (because we're trying to find $n$) is $2n = 2k$, which tells us $n = k$.  So we see that for arbitrary even $m \in \Bbb{N}$ we can always find an $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = m$.

Let $m \in \Bbb{N}$ and suppose $m$ is odd.  Then $m = 2k+1$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ and then $f(n) = 2k+1$ can be satisfied with the second piece of $f$ as follows:
$$ f(n) = -2n-1 = 2k+1 \implies n = -k-1.$$
That is, for arbitrary odd $m \in \Bbb{N}$ we can always find an $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = n$.

For injectivity, each piece can be done separately:
$$ 2m = 2n \implies m = n \implies \text{ first piece is injective}$$
$$ -2m-1 = -2n-1 \implies m = n \implies \text{ second piece is injective}$$
Finally we must consider the "mingling" of the pieces.
$$ 2m = -2n-1 \implies 2(m+n) = -1 \implies m+n = -\frac12,$$
which is a contradiction since $m$ and $n$ are both supposed to be integers.

Comment: Forgot that function is F : Z -> N and 0. 

I have to learn to write proper math text with some editor.

Comment: Ok, will update accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your answer. You have done injectivity differently than I. Now when we are talking about integers, it is enough that I write, like you did, "suppose m is even/odd"?

Comment: @Mikoyan yes, it's fine to break proofs into cases as long as those cases cover all possibilities.  Here the only two possibilities are even and odd.

Comment: Yeah. Although I obviously realized that second part of function gives odd values, I didn't understand that I can use it in my proof.

Comment: Is it possible to show surjectivity same way as I did in OP (assuming it is correct), and then show injectivity like you did? I don't see a problem there, but it could be just me.

Comment: @Mikoyan I misread your even/odd question.  There's no need to mention even vs. odd for the injectivity proof.  We did surjectivity basically the same, I just wrote out more of the details, which I wouldn't recommend skipping.

Comment: I'll study how you did it, I don't yet fully understand it. The way I did it is probably enough for my purposes, but of course I wan't to learn more.

Comment: @Mikoyan, your surjective proof is basically identical to my "$m$ is even" case but it is important to explicitly state that you are assuming $y$ is even since otherwise $y/2$ is not an integer.   I updated my even case to include more detail and changed the conclusion of it and the odd case to use $n$ instead of $k$ since $n$ makes more sense.

Comment: "it is important to explicitly state that you are assuming y is even since otherwise y/2 is not an integer. "

Heureka. Thanks.

Comment: can you say am I doing something wrong here? 

When $f(n) = 2n, f(n)$ is even because n is integer. Then $y = 2n  -> n = y/2$, which is integer because $y$ is even.

When $f(n) = -2n - 1$, $n$ is odd, so $y = 2k + 1$. Now $-2n - 1 = 2k + 1 -> -2n = 2k + 2 -> n = -k -1, k$ is $Z$. 

Injectivity. Same way as in OP, but "mingling" part is: $2n = -2n -1 -> 4n = -1 -> n = -(1/4)$ which is contradiction since $n$ is at least $0$ and integer.

Comment: @Mikoyan $f(n)$ is odd, not $n$ is odd (in the second case). For the mingling case, don't use the same variable ($n$) for both pieces, because the idea is that each piece is supposed to be using a different input value.

Comment: yes, $f(n)$ is odd, not n, of course. Typo. In mingling part, would $n1 > 0, n2 < 0$ do it? 

$2n1 = -2n2 - 1 -> 2(n1 + n2) = -1 -> n1 + n2 = -(1/2)$ which is contradiction since $ n > 0$ and $n$ is integer.

Comment: @Mikoyan contradiction since $n_1$ and $n_2$ are both integers.  Otherwise looks good.

Comment: Thanks. Yes of course $n1$ and $n2$ are integers and not that $n > 0$ since I specified that $n2 < 0$. Stupid mistake again by myself.

Mingling those ($n1 >0, n2 < 0$) in injectivity part was the hardest part.

Answer (score 0):

First, we show that it is surjective. Let $n \in \mathbb N$. First suppose that it is even. Then $n=2k$ for some $k \geq 0$, and $f(k)=2k=n$. Now suppose it is odd. $n=2j+1$. But then choose $-n=-2j-1$, and more importantly, $f(-j)$ will suffice.

To show injectivity, assume that $f(x)=f(y)$. If $x,y>0$ or $x,y<0$, the result is trivial since the function is linear. Assume WLOG that $x<0$, $y\geq 0$. Then $f(x)=-2n-1$ and $f(y)=2y$. Then $-2n-1=2y$, or in other words, $2(n-y)=1$, a contradiction since $1$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote n = 2j + 1. I don't understand that part, at least not yet.

Comment: An integer $n$ is said to be *odd* if there exists some $j \in \mathbb Z$ so that $n=2j+1$. Similarly, an integer $k$ is said to be *even* if there exists some $w \in \mathbb Z$ so that $k=2w$.

Comment: In this case, we are restricting the definition to $\mathbb N$, but there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as the other answers, but presented in a more complicated way.

Let $f_+(x) = 2x, f_-(x) = -2x-1$. It is clear that these are bijections of $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, hence for any $C \subset \mathbb{R}$, we see that
the restrictions $f_+ \mid_C$, $f_- \mid_C$ are bijections onto $f_+(C), f_-(C)$ respectively.

Let $A= \{0,1,... \}, B=\{-1,-2,... \}$ and note that 
$A,B$ are a disjoint partition of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that $f=f_+$ on $A$
and $f=f_-$ on $B$.

Note that $f(A) = \{0,2,4,... \}, f(B) = \{ 1,3,5,... \}$ form a disjoint
partition of $\mathbb{N}_0$.

It follows that $f$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{N}_0$.